# Given two integer array nums of distinct items and target.return index for both arrays when difference between elements is equal to target value

Tags: arrays

if there is no item in both array whose difference is equal to the target then return [-1,-1] .example 1 : input: numsfirst = [3,4,10] input: numssecond = [1,4,8] input: target = 5 output: nums = [0,2] eg: 8 from numssecond - 3 from numfirst is equal to 5 which is target example 2: input: numsfirst = [2,4,10] input: numssecond = [1,4,8] input: target = 5 output: nums = = [-1,-1]​
Can you come up with complexicity O(n)

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int[] numsFirst = {3,4,10};
    int[] numsSecond = {1,4,8};
    
    int target = 15;
    
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    for(int i=0;i<numsFirst.length;i++) {
        // storing the element and its index as all element are distinct
        map.put(numsFirst[i],i);
    }
    // for storing the result
    int[] ans = new int[2];
    ans[0] = -1;
    ans[1] = -1;
    
    for(int i=0;i<numsSecond.length;i++) {
        int val = Math.abs(target-numsSecond[i]); // val = (5 - 8) == 3 "which is present in our map"
        if(map.containsKey(val)) {
            ans[0] = i;
            ans[1] = map.get(val);
            // break;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(ans[0]+" "+ ans[1]);
        
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).